# Infinite composition of cosine functions. And proof for convergent of its sequence. (Without Banach Fixed Point Thm)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

This is a very famous sequence $(a_n)$ s.t $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$.

But, I couldn't find any proof that only uses MVT to show $a_n$ is convergent, so I would like to have my solution to be verified. (This means it could be duplicated, but I couldn't find this kind of solution on my own.)

My approach:

> First of all, suppose that we know that $x=\cos x$ has a unique
> solution that is $x=a\approx 0.793$.
>
> And, note that since $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$, $|a_{n+1}|\leq 1$ for any n.
>
> To utilize MVT, let's construct a subsequence $(b_k)$. And let set of
> $a_n$ be $A$ and set of $b_k$ be $B$.
>
> We define $B=\left \{a_n:a_n \neq a  \right \}$
>
> From this, for any $k$ we get subinterval $[b_k,a]$ or $[a,b_k]$ of
> [-1,1].
>
> Let $g(x)=|\cos(x)|$. And note that $g(x)$ is differentiable on
> $(-1,1)$ and continuous on $[-1,1]$ so that $g(x)$ is differnetiable
> on $(b_k,a)$ or $(a,b_k)$ and continuous on $[b_k,a]$ or $[a,b_k]$.
>
> Then by MVT, we know there exists $c_1$ or $c_2$ s.t $${g}'(c_1)=-\sin
>  c_1=\frac{|\cos b_k|-|\cos a| }{b_k-a}$$ or $${g}'(c_2)=-\sin
>  c_2=\frac{|\cos a|-|\cos b_k| }{a-b_k}$$
>
> So, without loss of generallity, for any $b_k$ there exists $c$ s.t
> $$|\sin c|=\frac{||\cos b_k|-|\cos a|| }{|b_k-a|}\leq \sin1\approx
>  0.841$$
>
> Then, $$||\cos b_k|-|\cos a||=|\cos b_k-a|= |b_{k+1}-a|\leq 0.841
> *|b_k-a| $$
>
> This implies $\lim b_k=a$.
>
> And since $A=B\cup \left \{ a \right \} $, we conclude $\lim a_n=a$.
> [End of Proof]

I would like to get some verification for this proof. And, if it is correct, may I have some suggestions to make this proof simpler without changing a big idea?

Edit: I can see that I didn't need to use $g(x)=|\cos x|$.

Comment: You don't need a separate set $B$ - unless you start with $a_1=a$, you never get $a_n = a$ for $n \ge 2$. This is because on an interval where $\cos(x)$ is monotone, there's only one solution to $\cos(x)=a$. Also, you don't need separate $c_1$ and $c_2$ - you can just define $c$ case-wise. Otherwise, the proof approach appears correct.

Comment: @1Rock Yes, you're right. Thank you. Then, can I just say $|\sin c|=\frac{|\cos b_k-\cos a| }{|b_k-a|}$? So, It looks like it's better to say like this in general, for any unsure interval when using MVT.

Comment: Don't put in absolute values. If you reverse the order of $b_k$ and $a$ in the numerator as well as the denominator, you don't change the sign.